# What is the meaning of "<<<<<<< HEAD" in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

Well, I tried to make the title descriptive, but in case you missed it, I'm wondering what
`<<<<<<< HEAD` means in a bash script.

trying to run the script in question gives the error:

```
./rftest2: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'
./rftest2: line 8: `<<<<<<< HEAD'
```

In case more information is needed, here's the entire script ( which comes from https://github.com/fabianomathilde/RouteFlow/blob/master/rftest/rftest2 )

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EUID" != "0" ]; then
  echo "You must be root to run this script."
  exit 1
fi

<<<<<<< HEAD
ACTION=""
case "$1" in
--pox)
    ACTION="POX"
    ;;
--nox)
    ACTION="NOX"
    ;;
--floodlight)
    ACTION="FLOODLIGHT"
    ;;
--reset)
    ACTION="RESET"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Invalid argument: $1"
    echo "Options: "
    echo "    --pox: run using POX"
    echo "    --nox: run using NOX"
    echo "    --floodlight: run using Floodlight"
    echo "    --reset: stop running and clear data from previous executions"
    exit
    ;;
esac

=======
SCRIPT_NAME="rftest2"
>>>>>>> upstream/master
LXCDIR=/var/lib/lxc
MONGODB_CONF=/etc/mongodb.conf
MONGODB_PORT=27017
CONTROLLER_PORT=6633
RF_HOME=..
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$RF_HOME

cd $RF_HOME

wait_port_listen() {
    port=$1
    while ! `nc -z localhost $port` ; do
        echo -n .
        sleep 1
    done
}

echo_bold() {
    echo -e "\033[1m${1}\033[0m"
}

kill_process_tree() {
    top=$1
    pid=$2

    children=`ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${pid}`

    for child in $children
    do
        kill_process_tree 0 $child
    done

    if [ $top -eq 0 ]; then
        kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
    fi
}

reset() {
    init=$1;
    if [ $init -eq 1 ]; then
        echo_bold "-> Starting $SCRIPT_NAME";
    else
        echo_bold "-> Stopping child processes...";
        kill_process_tree 1 $$
    fi

    ovs-vsctl del-br dp0 &> /dev/null;
    ovs-vsctl emer-reset &> /dev/null;

    echo_bold "-> Stopping and resetting LXC VMs...";
    lxc-shutdown -n rfvmA;
    lxc-shutdown -n rfvmB;
    lxc-shutdown -n rfvmC;
    lxc-shutdown -n rfvmD;

    echo_bold "-> Deleting (previous) run data...";
    mongo db --eval "
        db.getCollection('rftable').drop(); 
        db.getCollection('rfconfig').drop(); 
        db.getCollection('rfstats').drop(); 
        db.getCollection('rfclient<->rfserver').drop(); 
        db.getCollection('rfserver<->rfproxy').drop();
    "

    rm -rf /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/opt/rfclient;
    rm -rf /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/opt/rfclient;
    rm -rf /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/opt/rfclient;
    rm -rf /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/opt/rfclient;
}
reset 1
trap "reset 0; exit 0" INT

<<<<<<< HEAD
if [ "$ACTION" != "RESET" ]; then
    echo_bold "-> Starting MongoDB..."
    mkdir $HOME/db
    mongod --quiet --dbpath $HOME/db --logpath /dev/null &
    wait_port_listen $MONGODB_PORT

    echo_bold "-> Starting the virtual machines..."
    # Create the rfclient dir
    mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/opt/rfclient
    mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/opt/rfclient
    mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/opt/rfclient
    mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/opt/rfclient

    # Copy the rfclient executable
    cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
    cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
    cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
    cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient

    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.so /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.so /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.so /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/usr/lib
    cp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.so /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/usr/lib

    # We need to start the VMs with different sleep times to guarantee their order.
    # This is a known Routeflow limitation, and we plan to eliminate it in the future.
    echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "sleep 10" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

    echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "sleep 15" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

    echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "sleep 20" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

    echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "sleep 25" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

    chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
    chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

    lxc-start -n rfvmA -d
    lxc-start -n rfvmB -d
    lxc-start -n rfvmC -d
    lxc-start -n rfvmD -d

    echo_bold "-> Starting the management network (br0)..."
    ovs-vsctl add-br br0
    ovs-vsctl add-port br0 rfvmA.0 
    ovs-vsctl add-port br0 rfvmB.0 
    ovs-vsctl add-port br0 rfvmC.0 
    ovs-vsctl add-port br0 rfvmD.0
    ifconfig br0 up
    ifconfig br0 192.169.1.1

    echo_bold "-> Starting the controller ($ACTION) and RFPRoxy..."
    case "$ACTION" in
    POX)
        cd pox
        ./pox.py --no-cli log.level --=INFO topology openflow.topology openflow.discovery rfproxy rfstats &
        cd - &> /dev/null
        ;;
    NOX)
        cd nox/build/src
        ./nox_core -i ptcp:$CONTROLLER_PORT rfproxy --verbose="rfproxy:ANY:INFO" &
        cd - &> /dev/null
        ;;
    FLOODLIGHT)
        cd floodlight
        ant run_floodlight &
        cd - &> /dev/null
        ;;
    esac
    wait_port_listen $CONTROLLER_PORT

    echo_bold "-> Starting RFServer..."
    ./rfserver/rfserver.py rftest/rftest2config.csv &

    echo_bold "-> Starting the control plane network (dp0 VS)..."
    ovs-vsctl add-br dp0
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.1
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.2
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.3
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.4
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.1
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.2
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.3
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.1
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.2
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.3
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.1
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.2
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.3
    ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.4
    ovs-vsctl set Bridge dp0 other-config:datapath-id=7266767372667673
    ovs-vsctl set-controller dp0 tcp:127.0.0.1:$CONTROLLER_PORT
    ifconfig dp0 up

    echo_bold "---"
    echo_bold "This test is up and running."
    echo_bold "Start Mininet:"
    echo_bold "  $ sudo mn --custom ~/mininet/custom/topo-4sw-4host.py --topo=rftopo"
    echo_bold "    --controller=remote --ip=10.0.2.2 --port=$CONTROLLER_PORT"
    echo_bold "Replace ADDRESS with the address of this host's interface connected "
    echo_bold "to the Mininet VM."
    echo_bold "Then try pinging everything:"
    echo_bold "  > pingall"
    echo_bold "You can stop this test by pressing CTRL+C."
    echo_bold "---"
    wait
fi
=======
echo_bold "-> Setting up the management bridge (lxcbr0)..."
ifconfig lxcbr0 192.169.1.1 up

echo_bold "-> Setting up MongoDB..."
sed -i "/bind_ip/c\bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.169.1.1" $MONGODB_CONF
service mongodb restart
wait_port_listen $MONGODB_PORT

echo_bold "-> Configuring the virtual machines..."
# Create the rfclient dir
mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/opt/rfclient
mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/opt/rfclient
mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/opt/rfclient
mkdir /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/opt/rfclient

# Copy the rfclient executable
cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient
cp build/rfclient /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/opt/rfclient/rfclient

# We sleep for a few seconds to wait for the interfaces to go up
echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "sleep 3" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "sleep 3" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "sleep 3" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

echo "#!/bin/sh" > /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "sleep 3" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/etc/init.d/quagga start" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
echo "/opt/rfclient/rfclient > /var/log/rfclient.log" >> /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmA/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmB/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmC/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh
chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/rfvmD/rootfs/root/run_rfclient.sh

echo_bold "-> Starting the virtual machines..."
lxc-start -n rfvmA -d
lxc-start -n rfvmB -d
lxc-start -n rfvmC -d
lxc-start -n rfvmD -d

echo_bold "-> Starting the controller and RFPRoxy..."
cd pox
./pox.py --no-cli log.level --=INFO topology openflow.topology openflow.discovery rfproxy rfstats &
cd -
wait_port_listen $CONTROLLER_PORT

echo_bold "-> Starting RFServer..."
./rfserver/rfserver.py rftest/rftest2config.csv &

echo_bold "-> Starting the control plane network (dp0 VS)..."
ovs-vsctl add-br dp0
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.1
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.2
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.3
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmA.4
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.1
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.2
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmB.3
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.1
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.2
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmC.3
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.1
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.2
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.3
ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 rfvmD.4
ovs-vsctl set Bridge dp0 other-config:datapath-id=7266767372667673
ovs-vsctl set-controller dp0 tcp:127.0.0.1:$CONTROLLER_PORT

echo_bold "---"
echo_bold "This test is up and running."
echo_bold "Start Mininet:"
echo_bold "  $ mn --custom ~/mininet/custom/topo-4sw-4host.py --topo=rftopo"
echo_bold "    --controller=remote --ip=ADDRESS --port=$CONTROLLER_PORT"
echo_bold "Replace ADDRESS with the address of this host's interface connected "
echo_bold "to the Mininet VM."
echo_bold "Then try pinging everything:"
echo_bold "  > pingall"
echo_bold "You can stop this test by pressing CTRL+C."
echo_bold "---"
wait

>>>>>>> upstream/master
exit 0
```

Comment: That's a merge conflict.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988610/i-cloned-a-git-repo-and-see-strange-texts-in-files-head-and

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file has been checked out of a version  control system (probably Git) and there was a conflict between local changes and changes on the server since the two were in sync. The part between the "<<<< HEAD" line and the "======" is from the "official" file in source control, and the part from there to the other marker with the ">>>>" is the local version.

As such, these sections represent alternative visions of what the script is supposed to do, and you really need the developer who made the changes to edit the file and resolve the conflicts (and presumably check his changes back in.)

Comment: seems more like git for me, especially if you take into account link to github account (: