# strange chars after git push "<<<<<<< HEAD"

Tags: git, bitbucket

i'm new using git (bitbucket) 
yesterday i made git commit and push, today i found strange chars on all my files like "<<<<<<< HEAD" and ">>>>>>> 3eabb8c0e5effecfac857956bb8e941616669bc5" and the whole project doesn't work. how can i solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i cloned a git repo and see strange texts in files. HEAD <<< and >>>>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988610/i-cloned-a-git-repo-and-see-strange-texts-in-files-head-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *merge conflict*, check `git status`, it should tell you that a merge is ongoing and which files are conflicting.

What you need to do is, deciding which version of both you want to keep, and remove the other one, including the `<<<...` at the top, `>>>...` at the bottom and `====` in the middle. After you've edited all files which conflicted, add them as usual with `git add` and commit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had some sort of merge conflict. 
git would have told you about it and what files.
run git conflict to start and fix them.

Always git rebase -i origin..... and squash your local commits into a single commit. This will replay your commit onto the latest HEAD appearing as a single commit. You will then have to deal with any conflicts via git conflict. Then finally git rebase --continue and git push
. Also remember to git fetch origin before you rebase too!

**EDIT**
Thanks to our learned friend, I now realise that these funky characters are in the remote. So my above answer now only serves as a reminder of how to work in normal practice. Its important that you read up on the following.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow

Comment: This is rarely the correct answer IMO. I see a lot of people going crazy with rebase in a tidying frenzy that ends up with ginormous commits that are practically worthless when investigating a bug, cherry-picking patches, or reverting changes. Plus depending on how your rebase goes, it's pretty easy to rewrite your history so that a forced push will cause headaches for the rest of the team to stay in sync.

Comment: Whats this frenzy your on about? Your simply making your changes on-top of the latest code; keeping your changes nice and clean when looking though the history you'd see a single commit. Where I work I commit often to my local branch rebase squashing my commits into a single commit as  I go then push. There's no force push. I think you miss understood my answer.

Comment: If you on about loosing history because people are doing multiple bits of large work and then squash committing. That's easily side-stepped by the developer having some basic house keeping skills creating branches per work item and getting them into master via pull requests.

Comment: Firstly, I agree with you that rebase is a great (possibly the best and my favorite) strategy for keeping feature branches up to date for easy fast-forward merges back to master. However, it's not clear from the OP whether that context is in play. It says these unresolved conflict messages have actually been committed to the source code *and pushed* to the remote. No branch was specified, so if this was the master branch, then a rebase fix would require rewriting history and a forced push, ergo breaking everyone's FF pulls.

Comment: Ah I see. Agree with you 100%. I didn't realise the OP had actually had a successful push. Like you suggest probably best cause of action is to indeed fix this going forward and pushing a new commit in rather than force pushing. Force pushing on a master branch with other people working on it can get heavy. Especially if the other contributors aren't aware of what skulduggery has gone on or are not very experienced.